# how to implement datepicker in jquery Dailogue box with cloned form

Tags: jquery

how to implement date picker inside jquery dialogue box.
my

> javascript:

```
  function new_dialog(type, row, id)

  var dlg = jQuery("#edit_form").clone();

  var Remarks = dlg.find("#dotnet_Remarks");
  var BuildDate = dlg.find("#dotnet_BuildDate")


  var config = {

      autoOpen: true,

      height: 500,

      width: 700,

      color: "red",

      modal: true,

      buttons: {

          "Create an record": save_data,

          "Cancel": function() {

              dlg.dialog("close");

          }

      },

      close: function() {

          dlg.remove();

      }

  };



  if (type === 'Edit') {

      config.title = "Edit Error Details";



      get_data();



      delete(config.buttons['Create an record']);

      config.buttons['Edit Error'] = function() {


          save_data();

      };

  }

  dlg.dialog(config);



  function get_data() {

      var _Remarks = row.children().get(19).innerText

      Remarks.val(_Remarks.trim());



      var _BuildDate = row.children().get(17).innerText

      BuildDate.val(_BuildDate.trim());

  }




  function save_data() {



      jQuery.ajax({



          type: "POST",

          url: 'update',

          data: {
              Remarks: Remarks.val(),
              id: id
          },

          dataType: 'html',

          success: function(data) {

              alert("Error Details Updated Succesfully")

              window.location.reload();



          }

      });

      dlg.dialog("close");

  }
  };

  function edit_dialog(t) {

      id = jQuery(t).attr("id")

      row = jQuery(t).parents('tr')

      new_dialog('Edit', row, id);

      return false;

  };
```

> html

```
<div class="span3" style ="padding-left:30px;">
  <div id="edit_form">

    <%= label :dotnet, :Remarks  %>

    <%=text_area :dotnet, :Remarks%>

 <%= label :dotnet, :BuildDate  %>

   <%=text_area :dotnet, :BuildDate%>

  </div>
```

`
i need to implement like jQuery('#date_picker').datepaicker().
inside dailogue box.

Comment: please post your full html and script. so it will be easy to understand the issue.

Comment: What is the problem???

Comment: not getting date picker textfeild id in dialogue box.ie when i click date textfield in dailogue box not getting datepicker pop-up.

Comment: i want to apply datepicker on jQuery('#dotnet_BuildDate').datepicker() but seems to be no effect on dailogue box when click on text area.